# Масштабирование оси в TChart

Tags: c++builder

Я настроил в оси нужные мне минимум и максимум и теперь хочу получить фиксированный шаг по сетке. Свойство Increment однако даёт мне шаг относительно нуля, а не относительно минимума.

Как получить последнее?

Comment: Что такое "шаг относительно нуля"? Поясните на примере, пожалуйста.

Comment: На оси у меня выделяется точка 0, а дальше идёт шаг. Но мне не нужно выделение нуля на оси, а выделение некоторой точки, от которой и отсчитывается шаг.

Answer (score 1):

Я попробовал вот так и получилось:

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{

```
Chart1->LeftAxis->Automatic = false;
Chart1->LeftAxis->AutomaticMaximum = false;
Chart1->LeftAxis->AutomaticMinimum = false;
Chart1->LeftAxis->Maximum = 1030;
Chart1->LeftAxis->Minimum = -230;
Chart1->LeftAxis->RoundFirstLabel = false;

for(int i = 0;i<=10000;++i)
{
    Series1->AddXY(i,0,"",clRed);
}
```

}